# Digitalpersona fingerprint reader Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8

Tags: c#, wpf, fingerprint

I'm trying to compare fingerprints using digitalpersona 4500. But inside `Verificator.Verify(features, template, ref result);` I'm getting an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8'

Any idea why this happening? Full code:

```
    public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\...\test.txt";
        
        DPFP.Verification.Verification Verificator = new DPFP.Verification.Verification();

        using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writetext.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(Sample.Bytes));
        }

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string readText = streamReader.ReadLine();
            DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result result = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();
            DPFP.FeatureSet features = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification);
            DPFP.Template template = new DPFP.Template();
            byte[] fingerprint = Convert.FromBase64String(readText);
            template.DeSerialize(fingerprint);
            Verificator.Verify(features, template, ref result);
        }
    }

    protected DPFP.FeatureSet ExtractFeatures(DPFP.Sample Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose Purpose)
    {
        DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction Extractor = new DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction();
        DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback feedback = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.None;
        DPFP.FeatureSet features = new DPFP.FeatureSet();
        Extractor.CreateFeatureSet(Sample, Purpose, ref feedback, ref features);
        if (feedback == DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good)
            return features;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could be lost of reasons.  Three common problems 1) You have wrong or old driver installed. 2) The reader is configured wrong 3) You are not getting a good response.  The best way is always use the vendor software to check every thing is set up properly before using in c#.  It will eliminate a lot of issues.  You may of already done that but it is not indicated in the question.

Comment: @jdweng Driver is up to date. Have tested by their software and comparer is working ok.

Comment: Put a break point on the Verify and see if the inputs look valid and not null.  It is either the input are bad or the reader is not configured properly.  For example the reader could be set to 19200 BAUD and the default for the API is 9600 BAUD.  This is just an example and do not know if you are using serial port, USB, or ethernet.  With USB you could be using wrong com port.  So I can help isolate issue but right now there isn't a obvious answer.

Comment: I am guessing that it is connected through USB or COM? check the cables, sometimes it's in the details. If in doubt, remove and re insert the plug into the PC.